# Saving and Loading files without using Context - Android

Tags: android, local-storage, android-context

### Heading

I have an android project and want to change it to a Clear-Architecture structure following this [post](https://fernandocejas.com/2014/09/03/architecting-android-the-clean-way/). 
I have thre layers, Data, Domain and Presentation. In my previous structure I was not interested in linking the Data access with Android specific components, and because of that I used Contexts to access the local files directory as showed below

```
   File file = new File(act.getFilesDir(), filename);
   FileOutputStream outputStream;

   try {
       outputStream = act.openFileOutput(filename, act.MODE_PRIVATE);
       outputStream.write(response.getBytes());
       outputStream.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
```

Variable act makes reference to the Activity, but now I don't want to have the Data layer (in which I will have the access to files) linked to Android specific things.

Is there a way to access the local directory without using an Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is really not possible to directly access local directory without going through context. If you are decoupling the data layer completely from Android components, one way would be to pass the File object returned by `act.getFilesDir()` as a parameter to your Data layer.